# Assigning a Value to All Points in a List

Tags: r, chi-squared

I have a set of true/false data I need to prepare for a chi-squared analysis in R. Currently it's organized by time of day in several lists. What would be the best way to add a variable to each of these lists for time of day, fill in each list's points with the time they were collected, then combine them into one table?

Comment: Hello, if you add a `dput(data)` of your data we will be able to help you better!

Comment: dput(data)? what's that?

Comment: Its a function that outputs whatever is in your object. I guess your set is either a matrix or dataframe. Run `dput()` and paste the result here so we know how your data looks like.